# JMeter and Azure Load Testing using AD Authentication - unable to read Key Vault Secrets

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, azure-secrets, azure-load-testing

I have a JMeter test that uses Azure AD authentication using username/password. The JMeter test works fine when the Username and Password are read from Excel or hard coded.

I need to run this test in Azure Load Test and have created a Key Vault in Azure with the credentials but unable to get my test to read the secrets.

I have posted snippets of my JMeter test below if anyone can have a look please, I think there is maybe something missing in one of the sections? If this looks correct then probably an issue with the Azure set up. I've stripped out the client_id, tenant_id, etc. in the below code.

The secrets in Azure Key Vault are named LoadTestUsername and LoadTestPassword.

**User Defined Variables**

```
<Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
  <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
    <elementProp name="username" elementType="Argument">
      <stringProp name="Argument.name">username</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__GetSecret(LoadTestUsername)} </stringProp>
      <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <elementProp name="password" elementType="Argument">
      <stringProp name="Argument.name">password</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__GetSecret(LoadTestPassword)} </stringProp>
      <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
  </collectionProp>
</Arguments>
```

**Get Token HTTP Sampler**

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Get Token" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="username" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${username}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">username</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="password" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">password</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${password}</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="grant_type" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">password</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">grant_type</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
```

**HTTP Header Manager**

```
 <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
            <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">Authorization</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">Bearer ${__property(access_token)}</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </HeaderManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/pnopjp/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/docs/azure-load-testing-stub.md#how-to-install):

> **How to install**
>
> Download jmeter-plugins-azure-load-testing-stub-?.?.?.jar file from [latest release](https://github.com/pnopjp/jmeter-plugins/releases/) and put it into lib/ext directory of JMeter (e.g. /usr/local/jmeter/lib/ext), then restart JMeter.

It will allow you to use [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) to generate __GetSecret() function syntax however I doubt you will be able to use it locally but it will run successfully in Azure.

More information:

- [Create configurable load tests with secrets and environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-parameterize-load-tests)
- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)